# How to assign a variable to a GET value in PHP

Tags: php, get, concatenation

`<a href="details.php?phoneid=1"><img src="phone01.jpg"></a>`

When I write the code like this it's working fine. But when I edit this to assign a php variable to GET value, it's not working.

`<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]?> " class="product" title="Product 1">`

Can someone pleas explain why ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to echo the variable:

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php echo $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]; ?>" >
```

You can also do it this way:

```
<?=$Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to either echo it, like this:

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php echo $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]; ?> " class="product" title="Product 1">
```

Or use shorttags:

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?=$Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]?> " class="product" title="Product 1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to `echo` it:

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php echo $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1] ?> class="product" title="Product 1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php echo $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]; ?> " class="product" title="Product 1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing this with short tags. I believe it gives better readability

```
<a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?=$Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]?>" class=.......
```